# Grabbing a header from a redirect request to an angular-js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, access-token

I have the following situation: I have two applications that I need to make talk to each other: a JSF login page and an angular-js application.  I cannot modify the JSF login page. I can modify the angular application.

A user logs in by accessing the JSF login page. A user access the JSF page from a browser and fills the log in form. If successfully authenticated, JSF will produce a token and send that token in a header with a redirect to the index.html that has the angular-js application.  How can the angular-js application grab that token from that redirect?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on from what kind of request do you need headers.

In case of `xhr`, most probably you will do your requests with `http` service. Its promise gets (in both states: failed and succeed) an `object` as an argument with a `header()` method, the one you need. You can get more information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data - {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the    transform functions.
> - status  - {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers - {function([headerName])} – Header getter    function.
> - config - {Object} – The configuration object that was used    to generate the request.
> - statusText {string} – HTTP status text of    the response.

**EDIT**

There are difficulties when you need to get headers not from an `xhr` but from the initial page request, before angular is bootstrapped. Unfortunately javascript can not access them.

One solution could be using [`cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) instead of header to store the data you need. But in this case you should do some changes on the request emitter side.

The other way, could be handling requests on the server, before html is being provided. Afterwards, you can pass them directly in markup, or remember them somehow, and send an `xhr` request for them directly from angular. But if you have a simple static page, you won`t be able to achieve it.

Comment: If I am angular, how can I gain access to the response of a request that I haven't done?

Comment: Some other application redirects to an angular application, and that redirect contains a header that I want to access in my angular application.

Comment: Could I use cookies to store the header in the browser with the previous app and then read those cookies with the new app? Can you read cookies across applications?

Comment: Ok, I have understood you. You have to get headers from the Initial Page Request, before angular is bootstraped. One moment, I`ll think on my answer.

Comment: And the page is simply static html? Or interpreted/compiled by something (php, ruby, aspb node ect.)?

Comment: The login page is a JSF page with the redirect being built by Java.  The second page (the angularjs page) is a static page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a http interceptor that will get the header from the http request, than store it in a cookie or in the local storage.

***EDIT***:
Try this:

```
module.factory('myTokenInterceptor', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {  
    var myTokenInterceptor =  { 
        'request': function(config) {
        if (config.url=='index.html') 
        {
         var myToken=config.headers['myToken'];
         $cookies.put('myToken', myToken);

        };

    }
    };
    return myTokenInterceptor;
}]);
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myTokenInterceptor');
}]);
```

"module" can be anyone of your angular app modules.
In your controller, you can get the value of the token by using:

```
var token=$cookies.get('myToken');
```

Comment: Can I share cookies across applications?

Comment: You dont have to use the cookies from the JSF application because your will get the token directly from the http header with the http interceptor

Answer (score 0):

I do have similar scenario.
Authenticating user by JSF Application login page (App1), and on link click invoking servlet, inside doPost() creating Cookie with token/JWT  and adding cookie into responds header and redirecting to Angular JS ( App 2).
Angular app reading token from cookie and working well in local environment. 
but the same not working with real domain name. getting cookie undefined.

Inside doPost() Domain.com/App1

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("AUTH_SESSION", URLEncoder.encode(
                token, "UTF-8"));
        cookie.setDomain(domain.com);
        cookie.setMaxAge(30);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(false);
        cookie.setPath(“/”);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
String redirectUrl = bean.getRedirectServletUrl();
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

Inside AngularApp
Domain.com/app2

```
angular.module('app').service('CookieInitializer',
  ['$cookies', 'Session', '$location', CookieInitializer]);

function CookieStateInitializer($cookies, Session, $location) {
  var init = function() {
    var cookie = $cookies.get('FS_SESSION'); // undefined when using domain name
```

both application are differentiated by context path. and proxy added to make both application working with same domain name.

```
Domain.com/app1
domain.com/app2 --> apphost.com:443
```